# how to display 2 images per page (pagination?)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make a voting system, like in "The Social Network". I'm wondering how I can display 2 images from my DB, per page and when the user clicks the "next" button a new page should be loaded with 2 different images. That sounds like pagination to me, I don't know how to structure the routes and controllers for a feature like this, any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

laravel already have this feature
you just need to use ->paginate in end of your query builder like below

```
DB::table('users')->paginate(15)
```

And in blade file you can sempley show pagination page by this code below

```
{{ $users->links() }}
```

for more information about laravel pagination you can see [in the document](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination)